# Edit navigation bar (Soft Buttons)?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, buttons, navigation-bar

I just bought a low-end Android tablet (using Android 4.2.2), and it has 6 virtual buttons on the bottom of the screen :

- Home
- Apps
- Back
- Volume down
- Volume up
- Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of a Pipo M6 tablet: maybe not the same as the OP says, but definitely related to the question]

I don't need the last 3, since I have physical buttons for the volume, and I rarely make screenshots. I looked for a way to remove them but couldn't find anything.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As I could not verify it myself, not an answer but a comment: you might wish to take a look at the Xposed module [Xposed Additions](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb). From its description: *includes Full control of how the device should react during USB Plug/UnPlug and button re-map which allows you to assign new actions to click or long press of each button, **including disabling it.*** Not sure if "disable" in this context means "remove", but certainly worth a try. Please let us know if it works, so I can make it an answer (or not :)

Comment: This [guide](https://github.com/snanmre/custom-navigation-bar) has some information on how to manually edit the navigation bar. It seems quite risky since you will have to rebuild and replace the System UI app, but this is the official way of doing it. Though it's for Android 4.4.2, it should work on versions up to Nougat.